# What does this line from an essay on T. S. Eliot mean?

Tags: poetry, literary-criticism, t-s-eliot

The following extract is from Charles Altieri's [essay](https://archive.org/details/cambridgecompani0000unse_i5e7/page/188/mode/2up) "Eliot's Impact on twentieth-century Anglo-American poetry" published in *The Cambridge Companion to T. S. Eliot*. Here, Altieri is talking about Eliot's unsuccessful use of impersonality<sup>1</sup> in his early poetry to combat the "dissociation of sensibility" that he bemoans in the essay 'The Metaphysical Poets':

> Eliot's own early poetry could only manage impersonality as an aspect of the dissociation of sensibility, so that rather than providing a cure it became the deepest symptom of the disease. For when the mind seeks such distance from the energies that put it into motion, it finds it almost impossible to escape what I call the "pathos of reflective distance" characterizing his first two volumes. **There the intensity and clarity of Eliot's lines oddly isolate the speaking from the speaker, perhaps from any possibility of correlating an agent's investments in a particular life and particular body with the structure for reflection that persons must employ—hence the "shadow" in *The Hollow Men*.**"  (p. 194)

Could anyone explain the reference to "the 'shadow' in *The Hollow Men*"? I *think* I'm able to follow what Altieri is saying up to that point, but I just can't find a way to connect the reference to the general meaning of this section.

#### Notes

<sup>1</sup> From earlier in the essay: "...[Eliot's] insistence on an impersonality that could combat that dissociation by treating art works as objective correlatives rather than as personal expressions or rhetorical performances." (p. 192)

#### References:

Altieri, Charles. "Eliot's impact on twentieth-century Anglo-American poetry." Chapter 14 in *The Cambridge Companion to T. S. Eliot*. Ed. A. David Moody. Cambridge: Cambridge UP, 1994. pp. 189–209. Retrieved from [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/cambridgecompani0000unse_i5e7/page/188/mode/2up) 13 November 2023.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altieri is arguing that although Eliot tried to combat the dissociation of sensibility with a poetics that relied on impersonality, in his early poems this very impersonality led only to a further distance between the cerebral and the emotional, or between observation and expression. This exacerbated rather than ameliorated the very dissociation of sensibility that his impersonal poetics were intended to cure. There is thus a gap between Eliot's idea (that impersonality will combat dissociation) and the reality (that this poetic practice ironically leads to further dissociation).

The last section of *The Hollow Men* describes the gap between idea and reality, intention and action, conception and creation, as the Shadow:

> Between the idea
> And the reality
> Between the motion
> And the act
> Falls the Shadow
>           *For Thine is the Kingdom*
>
> Between the conception
> And the creation
> Between the emotion
> And the response
> Falls the Shadow
>
> <sub>Eliot, T. S. *The Hollow Men*. 1925. ll. 72–82. Retrieved from [allpoetry.com](https://allpoetry.com/The-Hollow-Men) 13 November 2023.</sub>

Altieri is saying that the Shadow emblematizes the distance between Eliot's poetic aim and his poetic effect in his early works.

Comment: Thank you very much, verbose!